# what can i use instead of font-feature-settings: "case" 1;

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, font-feature-settings

I have a web page with a button, when button is clicked, am using `window.print()` to normally print content of my page. problem is that am using firago font with `font-feature-settings: "case" 1`; (it tranforms text to uppercase). generated pdf looks good, but when it is opened in adobe illustrator, it shows ???? this symbols. i had no idea what was the reason for that and finally I found that font-feature-settings: "case" 1; does something to the text that adobe illustrator can not see.
is there a javascript function to do same as `font-feature-settings: "case" 1;` ? i was googling but could not find an aswer.

Comment: I'm not totally clear what environment you are working in, but have you looked at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase

Comment: I did. toUppercase is not working on some foreign writings like Georgian (example: ეს არის წინადადების მაგალითი). font-feature is making this text uppercase, but javascript function does not.

Comment: Ah, I hadn’t appreciated the problem. It appears to be one being discussed at least for Chrome 5 years ago. Is it still not resolved? https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=865427

Comment: no, its not unfortunately